# Print Background colours in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I am trying to print a PHP generated document in chrome, on the browser it looks fine [Link to the page I want to print](http://www.abbeysoft.co.uk/adi/241/quote.php) But my printer will not print any coloured backgrounds, can anyone offer any suggestions please? Can I do this with CSS?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome

Comment: Chrome now allows `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` in the element CSS to print the background.

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355117/print-css-backgrounds-in-safari-chrome/9339257

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You adjust in the browser, whether the background colors and images are printed. See your browsers printing options.

[Google Chrome offers this feature starting from version 26](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113594) (march 2013).

Also [starting from version 17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339257/698168), Chrome allows changing the background print behavior programmatically by using `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` in the element CSS to print the background.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a vast majority of browsers disables background colors and images by default.

Comment: Does Google Chrome still support this option?  I'm seeing the option in the print dialog, but the background colors are still not showing up in the pdf

Comment: Can confirm that Chrome still supports `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 38):

Gordon's answer is great, but for people whose CSS skills are rusty, here's a more complete example.

Put the following in your document's `<head>` section.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print { body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } }
</style>
```

---

By the way, although Chrome/Chromium's print dialog now has a `Background graphics` checkbox, it only seems to work if you do not click `Print using system dialog` (observed with Chromium in Linux).

Comment: Equivalent with keeping media separated by style grouping:
```<style type="text/css" media="print">
body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
</style>```

Answer (score 6):

Chrome > Print (`cmd P`) > *click* More Settings > Options: *check* **Background graphics**

[image: Chrome Print Preview]