# Print MediaWiki tables in color

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

We have various tables in our wiki that use colors for different cells. However, when we print the pages (or view in print preview) the colors are not shown. Colored text is shown.

I have heard from a colleague that this has something to do with stylesheets (CSS?). Does anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In turns out this was a browser issue.

In Internet Explorer:

1. Go to **Tools -> Internet Options**.
2. In the Internet Options pop up, select the **Advanced** tab.
3. Scroll down to Printing and select **Print background colors and images**.
4. Press **OK**.

In Firefox:

1. Go to **File -> Page Setup**
2. In the Page Setup dialog, on the Format & Options tab, select **Print Background (colors & images)**
3. Press OK.

In Google Chrome: this is apparently not possible. See SuperUser questions ([Chrome print background images](https://superuser.com/questions/123642/chrome-print-background-images) and [Printing background colours in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome)) and this right here at StackOverflow: [Print Background colours in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome).