# Chrome/FF does not show HTML table background colors in printed PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, background-color

How do you set table cell colors in an html table exporting to PDF?  I'm dynamically generating content that even has `background-color: #ffffff` (or `red`) and displaying it on a web page, but the backgrounds of the cells just come through as white.  Basically every PDF writer I try (Chrome's, LisaNet, Firefox's) doesn't render any color.

Comment: How you export to PDF?

Comment: Using the built in PDF print function in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Ok, I'm not really into browser pdf exports. But if those exports are handled like print jobs... Well, fairly often printouts By pdf viewers ignore backgrounds by default, too.

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

In PDF is not supported the cell background. we only get in table background. and also padding value and margin value also not supported.