# Unable to print background-colors (css solution)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Im trying to learn how to enable print background-colors pages in **chrome** :

Take for example [**http://angularjs.org/**](http://angularjs.org/)

the main page is :

[image]

So If I click `print` ( <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd>) and mark the "background colors and images" - it does show the background colors which are future to be print :

[image]

All ok.

But If I navigate to another page [**http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02**](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) which also have background colors in it :

[image]

And when I try to print it - I see it in the preview pane **without** colors :

[image]

**My question is** : how did they do that ? ( or better , how can I make it print background colors ?)

I already read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome) that I should use `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;`

so I added it to the html via chrome developer toolbar , but it didn't help. ( when I clicked <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> again

[image]

What should I change in the css in order for it to print also background colors ?

related info , searching for `@media`  , found it under :

[image]

But I didn't find any related info there.

Comment: Do you have the media allocated to the `link` tag? say `all` or `print` as a value? because most of them set that as `screen`

Comment: @Mr.Alien added info at the bottom.

Comment: Yea, am not asking for the screens of angular, as am sure they did used, what about yours?

Comment: @Mr.Alien well , since I dont know how they did it , I cant test it on my own site..... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think you didn't got what I meant in the comments, anyways, so it's pretty simple, say am having an element, like

```
<div class="blow"></div>
```

With a `background` set to `tomato`, so inorder to make that work, first of all you have to be sure that you have `media` print set, like

```
@media print {
  /* Declarations go here */
}
```

**OR**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="print" />
```

---

Now, what you have to declare is

`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` in the property block, like

```
@media print, screen { /* Using for the screen as well */
    .blow {
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px; 
        background: tomato;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPhkn/) *(Only for `webkit` browsers i.e Chrome/Safari)*

In the above demo, you should be able to see the red block, even in the print preview window of your Chrome.

---

As you have commented, it works for me..

[image]

**OR**

[image]

---

Support for the same is dirty, for more information on the property, you can refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

[image]

> From MDN :
>
> #### Body element backgrounds are not printed
>
> Currently neither
>   Chrome nor Safari print backgrounds of the body element. If this
>   property is set to exact for the body element, it will apply only to
>   its descendants.
>
> #### Chrome clipped image bug
>
> When background images are clipped (for example, when using
>   background-image sprites), due to [Chromium bug 131054](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131054), they will
>   appear distorted when printed from the Chrome browser with
>   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact. Solid backgrounds and background images that are not clipped (i.e. have lower width and height than the
>   element to which they are applied) are printed correctly.
>
> #### External links
>
> WebKit bug [64583](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64583): "WIP: Add CSS property to control printing of backgrounds for individual elements"
>   CSSWG wiki: "[print-background](http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/print-backgrounds)" - a proposal to standardize this
>   property

Comment: I never knew `tomato` was a valid background colour. You've made my day, Mr. Alien!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That's one of my favorite :D

Answer (score 1):

Your background-color is probably overwritten. To achieve background-color for printing increase the specificity of your selector or add `!important` to the statement. Along with `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` this should work for you:

```
@media print {
    .mycontainer {
        background-color: #000 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `!important` statement?