# Can the html page run from local URL converted into pdf with colour in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have created a html page with bootstrap control and my own css. I am running the page through visual studio in chrome. I want this page to get converted into pdf with colours as it is displayed in chrome. I have not connected any printer to my system. If i give ctrl+P, my page is getting displayed without colours. 
I have used '**save as pdf**' extension of chrome for conversion.
It is saying '**cant access your local url**'. Is there a way to print the page in the same way as it is seen in browser as a pdf

Bootstrap controls like progress bar not getting appeared in print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Background colours in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome)

Comment: yes. -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact; is mentioned as an answer. I added that to my html page. But still my bootstrap controls like progress bar is appearing colourless in pdf. They are not visible at all.

Comment: Use Fullpage screen capture to convert to image and then print. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Answer (score 3):

Chrome “Save As PDF” works fine. You need to tick the “print background graphics” checkbox otherwise by default backgrounds are ignored.

However, the problem is that Bootstrap has included a reset for print media. What it does is to overwrite all background to white and foreground color to black, with !important.

What kills is the *!important*

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use one of the free online HTML-to-PDF conversion solutions.

Here's one for example: http://www.htmlpdf.com/

Keep in mind that some solutions may not give you the expected results. In this case just try another.

After you have found a working solution, just print the converted-HTML-to-PDF file that you downloaded.

Comment: But this works only for the hosted sites. Not for the sites run from localhost. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that this is for hosted sites. However, you can still try an _offline_ solution which is **Adobe Acrobat DC**.
Take a look here:
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/convert-html-to-pdf.html

Answer (score 1):

Chrome itself acts as a pdf writer and reader, as we already know. I'm not sure why the colours are missing in the preview for printing, still, give this a try:

After <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>, you'll see the `Print` - `Cancel` options, below which there is a Destination for you to choose.

It has Recent, Local and Cloud destinations with a choice from the local ones being displayed. Go ahead and change it to Save as pdf.

Now you can save the whole webpage with the colours too.

[Take a look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJuEH.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but found an easy solution. 
Simply get the google chrome extension called : FireShot

Get it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en

It will take full page screenshot of your HTML page and even local Html pages.
Then capture the full page.

After it will lead you to a new page with saving option. 
Beside “Email” I suggest you to click on “PDF”. Then it will lead you to Gmail so you can send yourself the PDF.

I don’t suggest to click on print, because in my case when I saved it, there was an issue with the pixels.

Very easy.

Answer (score -1):

[GoFullPage - Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) — works great for this case.