# How to make odd and even background visible on print?

Tags: css, printing, html-table, css-tables

How expert like you would you code an odd & even's tr background to be visible for print.

I tried without success to !important them in @media print

```
    @media print {
      table > tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: lightgrey!important;
      }
      table > tr:nth-child(even) {
      background: white!important;
      }
    }
```

Best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't table > tr > td work when using the child selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector)

Comment: Browsers tend to require the user to set an option which will print backgrounds. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

What works to allow the rest of the code to work was this :

```
@media print { body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } }
```